# php pdo code to search and echo from textbox

Tags: php, pdo

my form has receipt_no textbox..

I Need to search data on textbox blur event or key down event of textbox.

from this receipt_no textbox.I need to search database and echo values inside another textboxes...

please help...

```
<?php
function  myFunction()
{
if(isset($_POST['receipt_no']))
{       
    $receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no']; 
    $result = $database->getRow("SELECT receipt_no,scheme_name FROM scheme_master where receipt_no = :receipt_no",array(':receipt_no'=>$receipt_no));
    if($result!=0)
    {   
        while ($row = $result->fetchObject())
         {
          echo $row->scheme_name;
         }
    }
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text"  name="receipt_no" onblur="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

**echo value inside this textbox---**

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$scheme_name;?>" name="scheme" class="field size2" />
```

Comment: Do you have any clue about using AJAX? Because that's what you'll need.

Comment: You are trying to call a php function the way you would call a Javascript functinon. This is not going to work! You should look up some javascript/AJAX code on google: [http://www.w3schools.com/js/](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

Comment: You need some live search here is a good example hope it helps: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-live-search-in-php-and-mysql-with-jquery_309.html

Comment: i done need autocomplete or live search refrence.... i need to search on textbox blur event....and echo values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right two methods, PHP only and AJAX javascript as some have mentioned.

First PHP only:

```
<? $db=new PDO();
if($_POST&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT receipt_no,scheme_name FROM scheme_master WHERE receipt_no=:receipt_no');//not sure why you're entering an array?
    $result->bindParam(':receipt_no',$_POST['scheme'],PDO::PARAMETER);
    $result->execute();
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo$row['scheme_name'];
    }
}?>
<!--Form next-->
<form name='findReceipt' action='' method="POST">
    <input name='scheme' type='text' value='<?echo$scheme_name;?>'/>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Get'/>
</form>
```

You don't need the attribute `onblur` attribute for this method. This is a 'self' operating page method.

The next method is javascript method where the `onblur` attribute can be used:

```
myFunction(){
    var xmlhttp=XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST','getResult.php',false);
    xmlhttp.send("receipt_no="+this.value);//if this doesn't work, use the following line
    //document.getElementByName('scheme').value
    document.getElementById('resultHere').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

The above is a VERY basic function, it will not work in IE5-6 and may require some header data etc. And! For those that love the silly library jQuery

```
$('input[name="scheme"]').blur(function(){
    var self=this;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{receipt_no:$(self).value()},
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            if($(self).value().length<5)xhr.abort();
        },
        success:function(result){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Some may argue to use a `GET` method for this opposed to `POST` but I prefer POST overall.